# Upload video stored on google cloud to Youtube

Tags: youtube, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to upload a video file which is stored on Google Cloud to YouTube pro-grammatically (without user intervention)?  Preferably PHP.

I would like to run the application via a Cron job.

Can you point me to an example of how this is done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YouTube Data API to upload videos to YouTube programmatically. Its documentation is at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

I am not very familiar with it, but I don't think that it can read directly from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have since found a good solution to my problem.

Comment: @user3065698 Are you going to share it?